# Insert Viewport meta in HTML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

in my example I'd like to inject Javascript into the content of `UiWebView RSS_Dettaglio_Webv`. Why am I not able to insert viewport meta?

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
[RSS_Dettaglio_Webv loadRequest:request];
[RSS_Dettaglio_Webv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSString *javaScript = @"var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');\
viewPortTag.id=""viewport"";\
viewPortTag.name = ""viewport"";\
viewPortTag.content = ""width=320"";\
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);";

[RSS_Dettaglio_Webv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Answer (score 1):

`meta` tags are parsed when the document is loaded, but otherwise they'll be ignored. Note that I use pure js to detect viewport size, and adjust the html page to that.

**UPDATE**

If you must use the meta tag, you can load the HTML as a string rather than a file, modifying the string before loading it... something like this (untested code) - where you put "width:device-width" into the `meta` tag, then search and replace it:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"htm"];  
if (filePath) {  
    NSString *firstHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
    if (firstHTML) {
        NSString *html;
        html = [firstHTML stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"device-width" withString:@"320"];  
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
    }  
}
```

Comment: So I've no chances to inject "viewport" into the HTML before the page is shown on UiWebview?

Comment: Only by modifying the HTML (e.g. load it into a string, modify it, load the string into the UIWebView rather than the URL), or using `document.write()` in the `<head>`.

Comment: Could you be so kind to show me the procedure to edit the HTML before loading in into the web view?